# Default multiview projection schemes

Tags: drafting

"... a multiview projection is a technique of illustration by which a standardized series of orthographic two-dimensional pictures is constructed to represent the form of a three-dimensional object. Up to six pictures of an object are produced (called primary views), ..." (Source: [Wikipedia, Multiview projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_projection)). While the resulting six views of orthographic projection are the same, a difference in arrangement of these views around the viewing box, lead to two different projection schemes: first-angle and third-angle projections, with the chance to mix things up (to say the least) when drawings are transferred from one convention to another.

To mitigate this issue, the projection angle is denoted by a projection symbol on engineering drawings. This international symbol shows the projection (top and front view) of a truncated cone, that defines and identifies either first-angle or third-angle projection.

Other than that national and supra-national standardization tries to minimize confusion by the two concflicting systems. From [Wikipedia, Multiview projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiview_projection#Multiviews) we learn that first-angle projection is standard throughout Europe and Asia (excluding Japan). Whereas third-angle is standard in the USA, Japan, Canada, and Australia. The UK or at least some British companies, so the article claims, switched from first-angle to third-angle during World War II.

Which are the default multiview projection schemes for countries in Central and South America as well as Africa? Preferably backed by national regulations or standards, if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Africa is broadly split into First Angle for former European Colonies, and Third Angle for anywhere where American development is taking place. As such, finding a standard for each country would be exceptionally time consuming! Do you have any specific countries in mind that you're dealing with?